# Create Groups on XMPP server

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am making a chat application using xmpp/openfire and I want to make groups on the server, which **anyone on the server** can join.

Anyone please help me in the same.

Answer (score 4):

Like this way you can create group in Xmpp server

```
            SmackAndroid.init(SelectMembers.this);
            MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(xconnection, GroupName
                    + "@conference.fonechat.in");
            muc.create(my_number);
            setConfig(muc);
            muc = new MultiUserChat(xconnection, GroupName + "@conference.serverid");
            muc.join(my_number);
            for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
                muc.invite(phone.get(i).toString() + "@fonechat.in",
                        "Meet me in this excellent room");
```

//SetConfig function

```
    private void setConfig(MultiUserChat multiUserChat) {

    try {
        Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm();
        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
        for (Iterator<FormField> fields = submitForm.getFields(); fields
                .hasNext();) {
            FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
            if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType())
                    && field.getVariable() != null) {
                submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
            }
        }
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
        multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a persistent Multi-User Chat (MUC: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) room for each group.  You'll be able to send a message to everyone in the group, which is terribly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try QuickBlox.com they have a sample program too..